# observer work even don't use extension!

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, module, sales-order

I used an observer in my extension called `checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after` but I don't know why this observer work even customers do not use my extension!

My extension is custom shipping extension and for saving my orders with api in my shipping panel, should use observer

code is

```
<global>        
<events>
    <checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
        <observers>
            <mycompany_myextension_order_complete>
                <class>myextension/observer</class>
                <method>myextensionCompleteOrder</method>
            </mycompany_myextension_order_complete>
        </observers>
    </checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
</events>
</global>
```

How can I prevent load observer when customers do not select this shipping method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observer will always observe your event. In order to prevent it from calling whatever function you want to execute, you should set `if condition` in your observer function.

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer
{
   public function myextensionCompleteOrder($observer)
   {
      $quote  = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

      $shipping_method = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod(); //selected shipping method
      if ($shipping_method == 'your_shipping_method') {
         //do your stuff here
         //......
        }
   }
}
```

Hope this will help.